# Nested GROUP BY on single table using SUBSTRING_INDEX

Tags: sql, mariadb, mariadb-10.6

My current query return *expected O/P* when run on below sample, my question is about how to improve the query and its performance.

[Schema SQL](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9YjDbfg1XcMRCbZbWnFbkG/4)

```
CREATE TABLE function_groups (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
INSERT INTO function_groups (name) VALUES ('f1.g1.a1');
INSERT INTO function_groups (name) VALUES ('f1.g1.a2');
INSERT INTO function_groups (name) VALUES ('f1.g1.a3');
INSERT INTO function_groups (name) VALUES ('f1.g1.a4');

INSERT INTO function_groups (name) VALUES ('f1.g2.a1');
INSERT INTO function_groups (name) VALUES ('f1.g2.a2');
INSERT INTO function_groups (name) VALUES ('f1.g2.a3');
INSERT INTO function_groups (name) VALUES ('f1.g2.a4');


INSERT INTO function_groups (name) VALUES ('f2.g1.a1');
INSERT INTO function_groups (name) VALUES ('f2.g1.a2');
INSERT INTO function_groups (name) VALUES ('f2.g1.a3');
INSERT INTO function_groups (name) VALUES ('f2.g1.a4');

INSERT INTO function_groups (name) VALUES ('f2.g2.a1');
INSERT INTO function_groups (name) VALUES ('f2.g2.a2');
INSERT INTO function_groups (name) VALUES ('f2.g2.a3');
INSERT INTO function_groups (name) VALUES ('f2.g2.a4');
```

**Expected O/P**

```
id  groups
f1  [{"id": "f1.g1", "actions": [{"id": 1, "name": "f1.g1.a1"}, {"id": 2, "name": "f1.g1.a2"}, {"id": 3, "name": "f1.g1.a3"}, {"id": 4, "name": "f1.g1.a4"}]}, {"id": "f1.g2", "actions": [{"id": 5, "name": "f1.g2.a1"}, {"id": 6, "name": "f1.g2.a2"}, {"id": 7, "name": "f1.g2.a3"}, {"id": 8, "name": "f1.g2.a4"}]}]
f2  [{"id": "f2.g1", "actions": [{"id": 9, "name": "f2.g1.a1"}, {"id": 10, "name": "f2.g1.a2"}, {"id": 11, "name": "f2.g1.a3"}, {"id": 12, "name": "f2.g1.a4"}]}, {"id": "f2.g2", "actions": [{"id": 13, "name": "f2.g2.a1"}, {"id": 14, "name": "f2.g2.a2"}, {"id": 15, "name": "f2.g2.a3"}, {"id": 16, "name": "f2.g2.a4"}]}]
```

**Query SQL**

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.name, '.', 1) AS id,
    (SELECT 
            JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('id',
                                t2.id,
                                'actions',
                                (SELECT 
                                        JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('id', t3.id, 'name', t3.name))
                                    FROM
                                        function_groups t3
                                    WHERE
                                        t2.id = SUBSTRING_INDEX(t3.name, '.', 2)
                                    GROUP BY t2.id)))
        FROM
            (SELECT 
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.name, '.', 2) AS id
            FROM
                function_groups t2
            GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.name, '.', 2)) t2
        WHERE
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.id, '.', 1) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.name, '.', 1)
        GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.id, '.', 1)) AS groups
FROM
    function_groups t1
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.name, '.', 1)
```

Comment: For starters, string operations cost time, so don'save data delimitered please check te discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad also see te query plan. Did you add an index on name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing data structure will be the best option, but if it's not possible, then use `group by` only if it's needed, use `LIKE` rather than substring on column to use index (if any will be created).

Refactored query

```
SELECT 
    distinct SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.name, '.', 1) AS name_id,
    (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('id',
                                t2.name_id,
                                'actions',
                                (SELECT 
                                        JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('id', t3.id, 'name', t3.name))
                                    FROM
                                        function_groups t3
                                    WHERE
                                        t3.name LIKE concat(t2.name_id,'.%')
                                    )))
        FROM
            (SELECT 
                distinct SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.name, '.', 2) AS name_id
            FROM
                function_groups t2) t2
        WHERE
            t2.name_id LIKE concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.name, '.', 1),'.%')
       ) AS groups
FROM function_groups t1
```

**New query EXPLAIN plan**

| id | select_type and table | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY t1 | Using index; Using temporary |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | Using where |
| 4 | DERIVED t2 | Using index; Using temporary |
| 3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY t3 | Using where; Using index |

**Old query EXPLAIN plan**

| id | select_type and table | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY t1 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | Using where |
| 4 | DERIVED t2 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY t3 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=90a01808eb1bbf9b0ac989ecfe2c033b)

Comment: Considering data structure alternatives was already option on my mind (found it best option query data and make processing on server transformer layer.) = much better,
BTW: applied your improved query with some performance enhance... and query plan is better. Thanks!